# Trying to count record by user id

Tags: laravel, model

I am trying to get record by user id.This is working for login user .
But I am Trying to get details for all users .Not only.
Here is model

```
    public function referrer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'referred_by');
}

public function referrals()
{

return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referred_by');

}
```

Now I am Getting refferals no from this code.

```
   $referrals=auth()->user()->referrals()->count();
```

BUt I am Nedd to get same result for every  user listing ..
means I need to change this query.by user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case you must be use `withCount()` method

```
$users = User::withCount('referrals')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    dd($user->referrals_count);
}
```

Comment: you can aslo specify 'referrals_count' this key

Comment: `User::withCount('referrals as ref_count')`

Comment: @ How can I count all referals ..and then click on them then show all list of referrals

Comment: Davit @For example I Have Count nine refferal then ..How can show all 9 details on click

Comment: Davit@you there?